# Trying to get boolean value for session

Tags: php, sql, session

This code is outputting session variables i am trying to get the access level and put it into a session i already have an output for my username and password. I am trying to write a sql query that will retrieve the boolean and output it to Session_Access

```
if($count==1){
echo '{"response":{"error": "1"}}';
session_start();
// Register $myusername, $mypassword 
$_SESSION['lecture'] = "$myusername";
$_SESSION['lecture_pass'] = "$mypassword";
if ($lecture_ass = "SELECT Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword' FROM $tbl_name WHERE AccessLevel = 0;;"){
$_SESSION['lecture_access'];}
else if ($student_ass = "SELECT Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword' FROM $tbl_name WHERE AccessLevel = 1;;"){
$_SESSION['student_access']; 
}
else {
echo '{"response":{"error": "0"}}';
}
}
```

Comment: Those queries are not valid and you are not executing any query and you are not assigning anything to the session vars in the `if`.

Comment: The are a number of problems.  Basic variable assignment issues, attempts to magically query a database without using any sort of DB connection/querying methods, etc.  Seems like you need to take a step back and learn some of the fundamentals in this area.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['lecture_access'];` does nothing. You must assign some kind of value to it.

May I suggest:

```
$_SESSION['access'] = 'lecture';
// or:
$_SESSION['access'] = 'student';
```

It should also be noted that you are not executing those queries, they are simply strings, meaning that `$lecture_ass` will always be a truthy value, and "lecture" access will always be given. You need to execute the queries and check for result rows.